# PHP Blank page when i process the form

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I was about 1 or 2 hours looking for the answer on the questions previously made​​, modify certain things in the code, I try all to throw some kind of error in the code, but for all that I could made and still directing me to a **BLANK PAGE**

This code is a search engine of auto parts, where i put a numeric value or description **%$buscar%** and displays a table of all search results or search specific

this is the PHP with conection to DB and Query's:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // Report on all errors
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
if ($_POST['buscar'])
{
// Take te value
$buscar = $_POST['buscar'];
// Si está vacío, lo informamos, sino realizamos la búsqueda
if(empty($buscar))
{
echo "No se ha ingresado una cadena a buscar";
}else{
//Conection to DB
$servidor = "localhost"; //Nombre del servidor
$usuario = "myuser"; //Nombre de usuario en tu servidor
$password = "mypass"; //Contraseña del usuario
$base = "dbname"; //Nombre de la BD
//conection
$link = mysqli_connect("$servidor","$usuario","$password","$base") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
//Query:
$query = "SELECT * FROM repuestos WHERE id LIKE '%$buscar%' AND descripcion LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY id" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 
//execute the query.
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
//display information: 
while ($field = mysqli_fetch_field($result)){ 
        echo "<td>$field->name</td> \n"; 
} 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<table border = '1'> \n"; 
//Show Table names
echo "<tr> \n"; 

echo "</tr> \n"; 
    do { 
        echo "<tr> \n"; 

        echo "<td>".$row["id"]."</td> \n"; 

        echo "<td>".$row["descripcion"]."</td> \n"; 

        echo "<td>".$row["cantidad"]."</td> \n"; 

        echo "</tr> \n"; 

  } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));

        echo "</table> \n"; 
echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro !"; 
} 
}
}
?>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

**i put the Fetch_field before the first fecth_array and now the page give me the names of the rows (id, descripcion, cantidad) but no table and no records..**

This if the Form IF i had the problem there...

```
<form method="post" action="buscarep1.php">
                        <label>Numero  o Descripción del Repuesto<br />
                        </label>
                        <input name="buscar" placeholder="Escriba Aquí" id="buscar">
    <input id="submit" name="buscar" type="submit" value="buscar">

     <input type="hidden" value="buscar" size="40">
                    </form>
```

i'm using..: 
**xampp, php with phpmyadmin**

**Thanks to anyone who can figure out what's going on here!**

Comment: first of all use `if(isset($_POST['buscar']))` instead  `if($_POST['buscar'])` then check is value set or not from your form may be you are missing something in your form.

Comment: i change it, and still with the blank page... i edit the question and i put the form code..

Comment: `<input id="submit" name="buscar" type="submit" value="buscar">` this should be `<button name='submit' type='submit' value='WhatEverYouWant'>Submit</button>`

Comment: `<input name="buscar" placeholder="Escriba Aquí" id="buscar">`  should be `<input type="text" name="buscar" placeholder="Escriba Aquí" id="buscar">`

Comment: Is the result page truly a blank page (no content if you go view source) or does it have an empty table?  I have never used mysqli_fetch_field, but it may be that by calling mysqli_fetch_row before the field fetch, you may be moving the cursor forward in the result set and not fetching what you intended.

Comment: @user1767434 i change it on the form, and well still blank page on the php

Comment: @AngusAtkins-Trimnell yes is a trule blank page, no type of content just nothing... i'm trying to see what are you saying about the fetch_field and rows but i dont understand completely..

Comment: @AngusAtkins-Trimnell oh! i change the fetch_field and put it before the rows (fetch_array) now the page show me the titles of the rows (id, descripcion, cantidad) but w/o table and no records

Comment: Well, that sounds like a little progress.  I assume you are sure that your query returns results.  Is that so?  To check that, I would suggest echoing the result of mysqli_num_rows.

Comment: Another thing that I am noticing is that you are calling mysqli_fetch_array in two different while loops.  I would recommend removing the outer while loop, echoing the <table> tag outside of any loop and changing the inner do-while loop to a straight while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $buscar = $_REQUEST['buscar'];
    if(empty($buscar)) {
        echo "No se ha ingresado una cadena a buscar";
    }else{
        $servidor = "localhost";
        $usuario = "myuser";
        $password = "mypass";
        $base = "dbname";
        $link = mysqli_connect("$servidor","$usuario","$password","$base") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
        $query = "SELECT id,descripcion,cantidad FROM repuestos WHERE id LIKE '%$buscar%' AND descripcion LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY id" or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
        if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
            echo "<table border = '1'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>Descripcion</td>
                        <td>Cantidad</td>
                    </tr>"; 
            if ($result->num_rows>0){
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                            <td>".$row["descripcion"]."</td>
                            <td>".$row["cantidad"]."</td>
                          </tr>"; 
                }
            } else {
                echo "<tr>
                        <td colspan='3'>No se ha encontrado ningún registro</td>
                      </tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
}
```

Looks a little cleaner in mho. You're also doing a string search on field "id", this is usually a type int field, but it may be different in your design.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it works for me... now the code show the table but no records... and i have some records on the test db, and thx it helps

Comment: ok look what i did, your answer give me the table really good but w/o results..(what i search) for test i change the %$buscar% on the query for a exactly value and that give me all the table that i want with results and etc, the problem i think is on the %$buscar% but i dont know much about it :S

Comment: Do echo $buscar after $buscar = $_REQUEST['buscar'];

Comment: ok, i put it, and table dissapear and only show the word or number that i put on search... i think i'm gonna make a new question later..